# How can I support comments when eval'ing a file to set environment variables for a single command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a project with a file `variables.env` and add `VAR_THREE` and comment it as follows:

```
VAR_ONE=val1
VAR_TWO=val2

# comment the purpose of the new variable
VAR_THREE=val3
```

From the command line I run this to set the variables and launch the program (run via an existing shell script in the project):

```
eval $(cat variables.env) java -jar my.jar
```

The comment seems to apply to everything afterwards including the `java` command, evident by checking `echo $VAR_THREE` does not have a value and I get no output from my .jar. If I leave my comment out of `variables.env` `VAR_THREE` is set and the program runs and produces output.

**Is there a way to allow comments in the variables file without it applying to subsequent lines and commands?**

Comment: The band-aid approach is to quote `"$(cat variables.env)"`, as not quoting puts everything into a single line (look at the output after setting `set -x` to see that), but `eval` and `cat` used in this way aren't best practices anyway, so better see Charles' answer.

Comment: @BenjaminW., ...does that actually work? If you're keeping the newlines, then you no longer have the assignments as part of the same simple command, so you no longer get the automatic export and scoping behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As in they won't be part of the environment? You're right.

Comment: So, the *actual* band-aid approach would be to use `eval $(sed '/^#/d' variables.env)`.

Comment: Is `variable.env` *really* a shell file, or a `.env`-like file that uses something similar to shell syntax?

Comment: @BenjaminW. do you have any references explaining why `eval` and `cat` used in this way isn't best practice and what is and why (for example @CharelsDuffy 's apporach).

Comment: @chepner it is file that contains just multiple variables and their values just like the above [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), although real values instead of the trivial example

Comment: It's not as simple as "just ... variables and their values". Consider `x="a\nb"`; in `bash`, that's a string consisting of the four characters `a`, ``\``, `n`, and `b`. In a `.env` file, that's a string consisting of *three* characters: `a`, a newline, and `b`. It's not obvious that you *can* simply evaluate the contents as if it were a shell script.

Comment: @chepner so would an example such as yours give a different result with `eval $(cat variables.env) ...` to the `... . variables.env; ...` answer below?

Comment: They'd be the same, since both process the assignment as a shell assignment, but would be different from how a `dotenv` processor would interpret it. The important thing is to know what conventions and rules `variables.env` was created to follow.

Answer (score 4):

The easy thing is to use a subshell.

```
(set -a; . variables.env; exec java -jar my.jar)
```

To break this down into its component parts:

- `( ... )` puts the entire code inside a subshell -- a copy of the shell created with `fork()` but no `exec`-family call -- so none of the variables will persist past its completion.
- `set -a` tells the shell to automatically export any variables to the environment (so they'll be visible to the `java` subprocess). Because of the subshell, this is still limited in scope to the code run here.
- `. variables.env` is a more portable equivalent to `source variables.env`, running the contents of `variables.env` as a script.
- `exec` tells the already-existing subshell to *replace itself* with the `java` executable. Without `exec` (and absent some scenario-specific/undocumented runtime optimizations), running an external command creates a new subshell, tells that *new* subshell to replace itself with the `java` executable, and then waits for the new subshell to exit; by running `exec java`, we consume the subshell we already made, rather than creating a second one.

...and as an extra benefit, you don't get the undesired side effects of `eval` (causing an extra pass of string-splitting, glob expansion, and other potential confusion when passing arguments that contain whitespace or other syntax-sensitive characters).